# add more output tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
# Display Entry in a Label

from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

def returnEntry(arg=None):
    """Gets the result from Entry and return it to the Label"""
    result = myEntry.get()
    resultLabel.config(text=result)

# Create the Entry widget
myEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
myEntry.focus()
myEntry.bind("<Return>",returnEntry)
myEntry.pack()

# Create the Enter button
enterEntry = Button(root, text= "Enter", command=returnEntry)
enterEntry.pack(fill=X)

# Create and empty Label to put the result in
resultLabel = Label(root, text = "")
resultLabel.pack(fill=X)

root.geometry("+750+400")

root.mainloop()
```

How do I change the code to output more rows.
It changes the same row every time.
I tried to do something with fields but I had no idea what I was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the same object (`resultLabel`) over and over instead of creating a new one for each entry.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

def returnEntry(arg=None):
    """Gets the result from Entry and return it to the Label"""
    result = Label(root, width=20) # creating new label!!
    result.pack()
    result.config(text=myEntry.get())

# Create the Entry widget
myEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
myEntry.focus()
myEntry.bind("<Return>",returnEntry)
myEntry.pack()

# Create the Enter button
enterEntry = Button(root, text= "Enter", command=returnEntry)
enterEntry.pack(fill=X)

# Create and empty Label to put the result in
resultLabel = Label(root, text = "")
resultLabel.pack(fill=X)

root.geometry("+750+400")

root.mainloop()
```